# Creating React Native App with pdf annotation and sign on PDF Function

Tags: pdf, react-native, pdf-annotations

as I state on the title, I want to develop a project that having ability to open PDF file within the App (React Native), then later we can add annotation, notes, and sign on the PDF (put writing).
The pdf is from the server, so I assume we can call some kind of library that can open pdf and edit and have those features.

I tried browsing about it and found that PSPDFKit can be a solution, but the pricing is pretty much expensive. Is there any other library that can be use for this purpose?

Comment: You can try this 
https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib

Comment: I cant see option to annotate or sign/put writing into pdf on the fly, did this library have that option/feat ?

Comment: @baycisk let me know if you got something related to this?

Comment: None at the moment

Comment: @baycisk did you found a solution ? I need the same functional in my application.

Comment: Sorry, @Kholiavko, i didnt find any solutions for this

Comment: any body found any thing so far? for this problem?